# Unusual behaviour when applying scopes for filtering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, scopes

I have a model CoffeeShop with a column "wifi_restrictions" - an integer value which represents the number of hours you can use the wifi.

I am using the scopes gem, and would like it so that if I get a value in params of "0", then it will return all instances of CoffeeShop where wifi_restrictions = 0.

I have tried two methods to implement this.

Method 1:

In my form I have the following:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="no_wifi_restrictions" value="0">
```

In my model I have:

```
scope :wifi_restrictions, -> hours { where(wifi_restrictions: hours) }
```

And in my controller:

```
has_scope :wifi_restrictions, type: :integer
```

Result: undefined method `any?' for nil:NilClass

(I get this even when there are no params given for the scopes to filter, which I cannot wrap my head around).

---

Method 2:

In this method I have tried defining a new scope, "no_wifi_restrictions".

In my form I have the following:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="no_wifi_restrictions" value="true">
```

Model:

```
scope :no_wifi_restrictions, -> { where(wifi_restrictions: 0) }
```

Controller:

```
has_scope :no_wifi_restrictions, type: :boolean
```

Result:
This correctly filters when the value is "true" (no_wifi_restrictions=true), but when the value is "false" (no_wifi_restrictions=false), all instances are returned.
In the console, if I search CoffeeShop.no_wifi_restrictions, this filters correctly. But if I search CoffeeShop.where(no_wifi_restrictions: true) or CoffeeShop.where(no_wifi_restrictions: false), then I get no instances returned for either. So I'm unsure as to how it's working even 50% of the time, (and I'm not sure how to investigate what's going on under the hood).

Answer (score 0):

The following lines will not work:

```
CoffeeShop.where(no_wifi_restrictions: true)
CoffeeShop.where(no_wifi_restrictions: false)
```

These lines are trying to get all CoffeeShops where the column no_wifi_restrictions is true or false and I guess the CoffeeShops don't have that column.

If the param value is true, you want the scope to return all CoffeeShops where wifi_restrictions = 0 and else it should return all CoffeeShops where wifi_restrictions > 0.

Maybe it's also easier to add an boolean column for wifi restrictions. Looks like you're now trying to compare booleans with integers.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. You're absolutely right, the whole boolean vs integer issue was confusing me. I'm going to post an answer to my question in more detail for others to see how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I was thinking that the following would essentially transform an integer value into a boolean when calling the scoped method.

```
:no_wifi_restrictions, ->{ where(wifi_restrictions: 0) }
```

So I thought ok, if I send in my params no_wifi_restrictions=true, that it would return all instances of CoffeeShop which now return if I search in the console:

```
CoffeeShop.no_wifi_restrictions.
```

This is not how it works, however. Because in my params, it passes a value. So when I try that, with the param of "true" I get:

```
wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
```

The solution for this, I found, is the following:

```
scope :no_wifi_restrictions, -> hours { where(wifi_restrictions: hours) }
```

which can also be written like this:

```
scope :no_wifi_restrictions, -> hours { where("wifi_restrictions = ?", hours) }
```

What this does is allow for an argument to be passed to the scope (hours). So in this case I pass it the value of "0" in params and it will run the following:

```
CoffeeShop.where(wifi_restrictions: 0)
```

Essentially, the "hours" value is unnecessary for my needs because I don't really want or need a an argument, it's just that I have to provide a value in params (unless I'm mistaken, I have also tried removing the value attribute, but this results in a default value of "on").

Hence, the following will also work even though the argument passed is essentially redundant:

```
scope :no_wifi_restrictions, -> hours { where("wifi_restrictions = 0", hours) }
```

In this case, I could really give any value in params, such as:

```
value="this_is_a_useless_param"
```

...and it will still work, because all it needs is for an argument to be passed to the scope.

Perhaps someone knows a neater way of achieving this, but for now this worked for me.